# Repositioning text in a table in html

Tags: css, html

I have a basic html table. I'm trying to align "Tree" in the center of the 4 tree columns. No matter what numbers I enter into my margin, it doesn't seem to allign anymore to the right. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--2.10-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Trees </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8"/>
<style>
.center {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 25px;
    width: 30%;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width:25%">
    <caption>Tree Properties</caption>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan = "6">Characteristics </td>
        <th colspan = "5"> <div class = "center"> Tree </div> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> </th>
        <th> Pine </th>
        <th> Maple </th>
        <th> Oak </th>
        <th> Fir </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Average Height(ft) </th>
        <td> 100 </td>
        <td> 80 </td>
        <td> 90 </td>
        <td> 220 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Average Width(ft)</th>
        <td> 2.2 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 26 </td>
        <td> 5 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Typical Life Span(yrs) </th>
        <td> 0  </td>
        <td> 0 </td>
        <td> 0 </td>
        <td> 0 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Leaf Type </th>
        <td> 0 </td>
        <td> 0 </td>
        <td> 0  </td>
        <td> 0 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your margin from `margin: 0px 10px 0px 25px;` to  `margin:auto;`.
And add a th and change the colspan and columns as follows.

```
 <tr>
    <td rowspan = "6">Characteristics </td>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan = "4"> <div class = "center">Tree</div> </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: fair enough but he wants the box in the middle of the trees not the whole  table. can you sort that out if its  not semantic

Comment: Ah, I made edits to my answer. Since that column is a header anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/02r7fwr5/

**Css**

```
.center {
   display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    border:3px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-right:-27%;
}
```

Comment: It is not semantic html to use an anchor tag to center things.  Should use margin: auto;